# Spark concurrently jobs fail

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

If I run a single job with spark on yarn-client everything works fine, but on multiple (>1) concurrently jobs I get the following exception on the container nodes. I'm Using Spark 1.2 with CDH5.3 and Spark-Jobserver

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_3_piece0 of broadcast_3
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_3_piece0 of broadcast_3
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1008)
    ... 11 more
15/02/02 19:20:17 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1
15/02/02 19:20:17 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
15/02/02 19:20:17 INFO broadcast.TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 3
15/02/02 19:20:17 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
```

Comment: That looks a bit like a network issue. Do you have any firewall rules in place blocking torrent traffic?

Comment: between nodes of the cluster alle ports/ips are non blocking. if i run a single job, then everything works fine. The exception occurs only on multiple concurrency jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Check `SparkConf.set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "10000")` in SparkConf. It may be due value in spark.cleaner.ttl your program running time exceeds the corresponding value, this may happens. Just increase the value. its given in seconds.
For more details look at [configuration.html](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be the reason `spark.cleaner.ttl`, since it was deprecated since Spark1.4